# Using subversion for collaborative work on a website

Tags: svn, version-control, web-deployment

I'm struggling to find simple answers to what to me are simple questions.

What can and does subversion do for me (or any version control system)

Lets say I have a site with the following directory structure, lets call it MyUrl.com:

```
PHP
    >>> Nav
    >>> Lib

Public_html
           >>> Images
           >>> Pages
                    >>> More pages
           >>> CSS
           >>> JS
```

Two developers working on the site.

I want to create a working copy of this and have it as a staging area, one for each dev

**QUESTIONS**

Do I simply create folders e.g. `MyUrl.com/testSite` and `MyUrl.com/testSite2`, then copy it all in (using subversion) ?

Does subversion do it automatically somehow and create the staging URL for me (if i copy all to a folder then will lose relational links which point back to `/`)?

I see things like TortoiseSVN which talk about my windows machine, does that mean I set up my PC as a fully fledged web server including apache and all databases locally then develop there and commit up?

I can find a million tutorials on how to use subversion, once you're in it, but none which tell me how to actually start with a scenario such as mine, which cannot be out of the ordinary, surely?

A point in the right direction to something that can basically get me going would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't create a `testSite/` and `testSite2/` folders. You start by creating a *project*, then you `svn add` folders (and files) to it. Then your two developers can `svn checkout` this project, themselves, each to his/her own folder. (You could of course have testSite/ be the place which you first add folders from so only the second developer checks it out).

A subversion client does not know about the web, or URLs (except for repositories), or web serverד. It does not interact with these for you. You could `svn checkout` to a directory which is visible through your web server (just make sure it prevents you from accessing the `.svn` folders.

The reason you're not finding a tutorial about what you want to accomplish is that you want to use subversion for something beyond source/version control. Try [Googling for the combination](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=using+subversion+for+web+content), or more specifically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394662/best-way-to-use-svn-for-web-development) here on SO.

You might want to consult [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)'s website and perhaps its [user manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to understand what subversion is about (not as a tutorial necessarily).